# Run SP in AyncTask to fill spinner

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask

I need to populate a spinner using AsyncTask for better application performance.

Here is my code to catch data from SP:

```
public void fillSpinner ()
    {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement ps = null;

        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo mWifi = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

        if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
            System.out.println(":::WIFI OK");

            try {
                ConnectToSql connectToSql = new ConnectToSql();
                SqlConnect = connectToSql.connect();

                if (SqlConnect == null) {
                    showAlertDialogSQLConnectError();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                ConnectToSql connectToSql = new ConnectToSql();
                SqlConnect = connectToSql.connect();

                if (SqlConnect != null) {
                    String SPsql = "EXEC SP ?";
                    ps = SqlConnect.prepareStatement(SPsql);
                    ps.setEscapeProcessing(true);
                    ps.setQueryTimeout(500);
                    ps.setInt(1, SesId);
                    rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    List = new ArrayList<String>();
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        String s1 = rs.getString(1);
                        List.add(s1);
                    }

                    //Populate spinner
                    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, deadEndList);
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spn.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    spn.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
                    spn.setAdapter(adapter);

                } else {
                    ConnectionResult = "Check Connection";
                }
            } catch (SQLException se) {
                System.out.println("Error al ejecutar SQL" + se.getMessage());
                se.printStackTrace();
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error al ejecutar SQL: " + se.getMessage());
            } finally
            {if (mWifi.isConnected()) {
                try {
                    rs.close();
                    ps.close();
                    SqlConnect.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else showAlertDialogSQLConnectError();
            }
        }
        else showAlertDialogSQLConnectError();
    }
```

If i run fillSpinner() its works fine, but it slows app, and I get a message "Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

And i want to use AsyncTask but i got error:

#1

> FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
> Process: com.mskandroid, PID: 27532
> java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
> at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error al ejecutar SQL: TDS Protocol error:
> Invalid packet type 0x2

#2

> 2022-02-18 14:14:23.444 27828-27906/com.mskandroid E/AndroidRuntime:
> FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
> Process: com.mskandroid, PID: 27828
> java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
> at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error al ejecutar SQL: TDS Protocol error:
> Invalid packet type 0xff

Here is my code:

```
 private class fillData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            ShowProgressDialog.showSimpleProgressDialog(getActivity(),"title","msg",true);
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            System.out.println("execDoInBackground");           
            fillSpinner();

            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean value)
        {
            System.out.println("postExec");
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    ShowProgressDialog.removeSimpleProgressDialog();
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
```

Why if i populate spinner in main thread no error happens? I understand that the problem is in the error - "Invalid packet type 0xff", but I don't understand why it happens.

Comment: For what is worth *you must update the UI on the main thread*, there's no way around this. Now your problem is a SQL related one, you need to further isolate the parts at play to find out where your problem is (I'd like to point out that AsyncTask is a deprecated class on Android; usable, but eventually going away).

Comment: what can you advise if AsyncTask is deprecated?  Executor?

Comment: Well, the recommended approach is to leverage Coroutines. Short of that, yes, you'd need to manage an executor pool (but careful with lifecycles and threads). This is handled by you if you use coroutines.